# Can I craft Ender Lily seeds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Is it possible to craft Ender Lily seeds?

I am using the latest version of "The 1.7.10 Pack" modpack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's crafted with an Ender Eye and Grass Seeds.

[See the Wiki](https://ftbwiki.org/Ender-Lily_Seeds) for more information, but here is the crafting recipe on the page:

[image: Ender lily Seed recipe]

The Wiki also states that:

> Ender-Lily Seeds can only be crafted in the Agrarian Skies Mod Pack

So it looks like you'll need that mod pack if you don't have it.